# Visual Studio : IndexOutofRangeException

Tags: sql, oracle, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to access a table in Visual Studio 2012 and am using Oracle 11g as the back end.

This is my code part which is giving error:

```
 comm = new OracleCommand();
        comm.Connection = conn;
        comm.CommandText = "select * from message where send_username='" + username + "' or r_username='"+username+"' order by id desc";
        ds = new DataSet();
        da = new OracleDataAdapter(comm.CommandText, conn);
        da.Fill(ds, "message");
        dt = ds.Tables["message"];
```

The same query when i run in SQL Command Prompt, it gives me 3 tuples as output but in this it is giving error

```
There is no row at position 1.
```

It is only giving one particular row as output no matter whatever else i do.

Any idea what I am doing wrong ??

Comment: [SQL Injection](http://xkcd.com/327/) is a very bad idea.

Comment: Are you sure that this is the point where you get the exception? It says `no row` so it is where you try to read a row not where you try to reference a table

Answer (score 0):

```
if (ds.Tables.Count > 0 ) 
{ 
   dt = ds.Tables["message"];
}
```

And

```
if (ds.Tables["message"].Rows.Count > 0)
{
}
```

Comment: Count of the table is coming to be 3, which is right, but still it is showing There is no row at position 1.

Comment: Now it's not giving the error but still it's showing only one tuple as output instead of three ... ??

Comment: @user3334146: Probably Because, there are no rows presented!!1